# Differentiability of multi-variable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose we have the following function:
$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$$
Is this function differentiable at $(0,0)$? Are the partial derivatives continuous at $(0,0)$?

The answer says it is differentiable but the partials are not continuous at that point

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to apply the definition of partial derivative to find fx(x,y) and fy(x,y), but the resulting limit has absolute signs in it, so I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the differentiable question: If $f$ were differentiable at $(0,0),$ then as a function of $x,$ $f(x,x) = |x|$ would be differentiable at $0.$ Is this true?

Comment: No, when u evaluate the partial derivative using the definition of partial derivatives. I think u will get f_x and f_y to be 0 at the origin.

Comment: Right, will edit. Thanks to both of you.